# Get the previous key in a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I have used `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> lhmNotFinal` because it is important the order in which keys entered in the map. I get the value of my LinkedHashMap using this:

```java
for (String key:lhmNotFinal.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Now, I want to get the previous value of my key, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem related with a LinkedHashMap in general - it's a coding problem. You can do several things:

```
String tmp= null;

for (String key : lhmNotFinal.keySet()) {

    tmp = key ;    // after the first iteration you have your last key in tmp
}
```

Comment: `Set` doesn't have a `get` method.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Then it's only one solution from me ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the fun:

```
//
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
map.put( "key1", "value1" );
map.put( "key2", "value2" );

//
final ListIterator<String> keyListIterator = new ArrayList<String>( map.keySet() ).listIterator();
assertEquals( "key1", keyListIterator.next() );
assertEquals( "key2", keyListIterator.next() );
assertEquals( "key2", keyListIterator.previous() );
assertEquals( "key1", keyListIterator.previous() );
assertEquals( "key1", keyListIterator.next() );
assertEquals( "key2", keyListIterator.next() );
```